# Selecting the latest entry of multiple unique category ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, select, min

```
Table Name: entries
ID (int)
rootID (int) 
categoryID (int)
editDate (dateTime [ default null ])
createdDate (dateTime [ default NOW() ]) 

  +--+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
  |ID| rootID |categoryID|       editDate      |     createdDate     |
  +--+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
  | 1|    1   |     1    | 2018-05-02 18:59:01 | 2018-04-01 18:52:37 | 
  | 2|    1   |     1    |        null         | 2018-05-02 18:59:01 |
  | 3|    3   |     1    | 2018-06-10 19:32:01 | 2018-06-10 19:12:01 |
  | 4|    3   |     1    | 2018-07-11 18:52:01 | 2018-06-10 19:32:01 |
  | 5|    3   |     1    |        null         | 2018-07-11 18:52:01 |
  | 6|    6   |     1    | 2018-10-09 12:38:01 | 2018-10-09 12:27:01 |
  | 7|    6   |     1    |        null         | 2018-10-09 12:38:01 |
  | 8|    8   |     2    | 2018-11-09 08:12:11 | 2018-12-09 10:12:01 |
  | 9|    8   |     2    |        null         | 2018-11-09 08:12:11 |
  +--+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Hello, I am trying to select information from a table with this structure. I need to return all rows from category 1 from all rootID's but only where the editDate is null and also only the min(createdDate) from each rootID.

I'm hoping for a result of row 2, 5, and 7. However if the editDate value of ID[4] were to be replaced with NULL then ID 4 must be returned instead of 5 for rootID 3.

I've been trying to find a similar post, the closest I found was this one:
[SQL MIN Function with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617453/sql-min-function-with-where-clause)

I feel like I am close with one of the examples that I found there but they are using two tables and I have to use only this one.  Here is what I am trying right now:

```
SELECT * FROM entries e WHERE e.categoryID=1 AND e.editDate is NULL AND e.createdDate in(SELECT min(createdDate) FROM entries)
```

However this only returns one entry from the earliest created date from the first rootID. I'm having trouble understanding the query but I am starting to see how it's only referring to the one entry.

What I'm looking for is from categoryID=1, find the ID's of each different rootID with the earliest createdDate of rows with a NULL edit date. How can I alter this to return one from each root?  Thank you for your time everyone.  I will continue posting the SQL that try tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your example is that it's only selecting rows where the createdDate matches the one minimum createdDate from the entire table. That's what SELECT min(createdDate) FROM entries will do, return just one createdDate.

I think what you need to do is find a way to select the minimum createdDate for each given rootId. I would try something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM entries A
 WHERE A.categoryId = 1
   AND A.editDate IS NULL
   AND A.createdDate = (SELECT MIN(B.createdDate)
                          FROM entries B
                         WHERE A.rootId     = B.rootId
                           AND B.categoryId = 1
                           AND B.editDate  IS NULL);
```

This way, you're selecting from the table where the categoryId is 1, the editDate is null, and the createdDate matches the minimum createdDate for all the rows with categoryId = 1, editDate null, AND with the rootId that matches the row the outer query is looking at.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Shannon I'm going to give this a try right now.

Comment: Shannon! thank you for sharing this it works perfectly and thank you everyone else who put any thought at all into this.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to have been able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries A
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Id
    FROM entries B
    WHERE A.rootId = B.rootId
    AND A.categoryId = B.categoryId
    AND B.editDate IS NULL
    AND categoryId = 1
    AND A.createdDate = B.createdDate
)
GROUP BY rootId, categoryId
HAVING createdDate = MIN(createdDate)
```

Comment: This sounds like what I need but I am having some trouble with it.  I am getting an error at line 4 at the '1' in TOP 1.  Does this mean TOP 1 is not available in my version of MySQL? I believe it's 5.6.2

Comment: attention @Keith Harris

Comment: Oh... You're using MySQL, not SQL Server. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. But if I get the following error, am I just out of luck?: ( This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' )

Comment: MySQL syntax is tougher than I thought... I edited my answer. I think it will work this time.

Comment: @Kieth Harris thank you, Shannon's answer below worked for me but I'm going to try yours right now also to see if it works for me too

Comment: @Kieth Harris your post does seem to work bit it's approximately 4x slower than the solution Shannon posted.  Your query executed in 32.0 ms and Shannon Fallon's query ran at 8.0 ms with the same result.  Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 1):

This works both for SQL Server and MySQL

```
SELECT e.*
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT rootID, MIN(CASE WHEN editDate IS NULL THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS editDateId, MIN(createdDate) AS minCreatedDate
    FROM entries
    WHERE categoryID = 1
    GROUP BY rootID
  ) t
  JOIN  entries e
  ON    e.ID = (case when t.editDateId IS NOT NULL THEN editDateId END) OR
        (t.editDateId IS NULL AND createdDate = t.minCreatedDate)
```